# React Native: firebase auth/network-request-failed error when trying to create a new user, but not on login?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I have a simple React Native application where I added firebase into. I've added a firestore and setup Authorization on my firebase account. When trying to login with the set account, the login succeeds using the following code:

```
    const onButtonPress = () => {
        setErrorMessage(null);
        
        const auth = getAuth();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then((res) => {
                navigation.navigate('Main'); // When going to the same Stack.Screen you're already on, it won't do anything
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setErrorMessage('Error: ' + error.message);
            });
    }
```

However, when I try to register in the same manner, it fails with the following error:

```
Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed)
```

This is my register code:

```
    const onButtonPress = () => {
        if (!email || !password || !passwordRepeat) {
            setErrorMessage('Please fill in the entire form');
        } else if (password === passwordRepeat) {
            const auth = getAuth();
            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                .then((res) => {
                    setErrorMessage(null);
                    navigation.navigate('Main');
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setErrorMessage('Error: ' + error.message);
                });
        } else {
            setErrorMessage('Error: passwords don\'t match');
        }
    }
```

The "funny" thing is, when I try to login with a wrong account/password combination with my login-code, it gives the same error.

So since login works, but not with wrong account/pw combination and getting the same error as Register, I'm guessing my database setup etc is correct (since I can login), but during the create-account, something goes wrong?

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I can fix it so that I can create new users in my app?

EDIT: I'm also using Expo in this application and using "expo start" to test it on my personal Android device.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue up until now, turns out I using onChange in the  instead of onChangeText, and using it to set the state for the email and password, which in turn was setting the email and password as an object instead of a string.
Example:

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="Password"
  value={password}
  onChange={newText => {setPassword(newText)} //This should be onChangeText
  placeholderTextColor="black"
  style={styles.textInput}
  secureTextEntry
/>
```

Try to console.log() the values for your email and password before creating the user, perhaps you're doing something similar.